# Iterating through pandas string index turned them into floats

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file:

```
 SID    done    good_ecg    good_gsr    good_resp   comment
    436     0   1   1   
    2411        1   1   1   
    3858        0   1   1   
    4517        0   1   1   117 min diff between files
    9458        1   0   1   ######### error in my script
    9754        0   1   1   trigger fehler

        #REF!               
        88.8888888889
```

Which I load in a pandas dataframe it like this:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(f ,delimiter="\t", dtype="str", index_col='SID')
```

I want to iterate through the index and print each one. But when I try

```
for subj in df.index:
   print subj
```

I get

```
436.0
2411.0
...
```

Now there is this '.0' at the end of each number.  What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried iterating with `iterrows()` and have the same problem.

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: Here is the whole code I am using:

```
import pandas
def write(): 
   df = pandas.read_csv("overview.csv" ,delimiter="\t", dtype="str", index_col='SID')

   for subj in df.index: 
            print subj


write()
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem, can you post your data file online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah.  The `dtype` parameter doesn't apply to the `index_col`:

```
>>> !cat sindex.csv
a,b,c
123,50,R
234,51,R
>>> df = pd.read_csv("sindex.csv", dtype="str", index_col="a")
>>> df
      b  c
a         
123  50  R
234  51  R
>>> df.index
Int64Index([123, 234], dtype='int64', name='a')
```

Instead, read it in without an index_col (`None` is actually the default, so you don't need `index_col=None` at all, but here I'll be explicit) and then set the index:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("sindex.csv", dtype="str", index_col=None)
>>> df = df.set_index("a")
>>> df
      b  c
a         
123  50  R
234  51  R
>>> df.index
Index(['123', '234'], dtype='object', name='a')
```

(I can't think of circumstances under which df.index would have dtype object but when you iterate over it you'd get integers, but you didn't actually show any self-contained code that generated that problem.)

Comment: Hey @DSM, thank you for the help. I edited my question to include the code that reproduces the problem, but I think you were faster :-)